# Android - Two map views in one viewgroup

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, android-mapview, android-maps

I need to implement 2 MapViews, one displayed on the entire width and height of the screen and the other on top of this map but will be smaller. I need both MapViews to be displaying at the same time showing different maps. I know that this is not supported currently but I know work-arounds can be done, just not sure how to get the two maps in the same view and displaying at the same time anyone have any ideas or examples?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Framelayout for arranging a view on top of the other.

Framelayout can be used for overlapping views

```
 <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:hint="Search..."
        android:layout_margin="3dip"
         android:id="@+id/txtsearch"
        android:background="@drawable/searchback"            
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"    
        android:id="@+id/btntitlesearch"                 
        android:background="@drawable/searchbutton"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

This will make the button overlap the EditText

Answer (score 0):

Use an empty RelativeLayout as a container. This way, you can put two layouts on top of each other. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html

Just make one fill_parent

make your second whereever you want it (like android:layout_alignParentRight="true")

There you go!

Answer (score 0):

Before you get to far, I'd like to quote what Google says about running multiple `MapView`'s in the same `Activity`:

> "Only one MapActivity is supported per process. Multiple MapActivities running simultaneously are likely to interfere in unexpected and undesired ways."

It looks like an `Activity` only supports one `MapView`, so you may want to find a different design path.